# After adding Package ID(offered by store at the time of app name reservation) in Package.AppManifest file app stopped working

Tags: windows, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, visual-c#-express-2010

We have developed a Windows Phone 8 app through VS Express 2012 for Windows Phone and then the same solution is upgraded to 8.1 when opening through VS Express 2013 for Windows and when we tried to submit app we got certain errors like package ID & Publisher ID needs to be changed,we did the same & submitted the build but because of doing such changes build come back to splash without activity please let us know what is the problem but store has approved our app which is completely passive after changing Package ID(Given to us at the time of reserving app name) in Package.AppManifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the solution got upgraded,you may try to test it on an emulator first which will be helpful if there is any problem in the app.From my experience, the modified publisher ID and product ID won't be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for replying but see the thing is If I again change Package ID to default, solution start working again and We are able to deploy the build thereafter but that XAP is not accepted by store as the Package ID does not match with provided Package ID;If modified Package ID is not the reason the XAP should not get deployed after setting Package ID'S value back to default.

Comment: Are you sure you did not change any other fields like the permissions and capabilities.I have submitted some apps to store but never faced such a problem.A good practice is to maintain backup copies,so that if anything goes wrong you can revert back at any step.By the way can you give more details about the app.

Comment: Yes,I mistakenly unchecked a capability due to which this problem occurred,Thanks Abhi!